# Association between nominal variable and ordinal variable using chi-square test

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, biostatistics

I want to see the association between a **nominal variable** (with 3 categories) and an **ordinal variable**, **only** by using a Chi-square test. But the assumptions for the chi-square test are violated. Is it right to use the linear-by-linear association test or the Likelihood ratio test?

Comment: better, if you mention problem and objectives  with a few details including data

Comment: I want to correlate an ordinal (independent) variable and a nominal (dependent) variable. Under some research I found that the proper statistical test for this occasion is the chi-square test.

Comment: What is your measure of correlation or formula ?